# .CSV Upload to BigQuery table 'truncating' string values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a table within BigQuery by uploading a .CSV file.

[image]

The .CSV file has several columns including an EAN column which has various entries of lengths 8, 11, 12 and 13 characters. I defined this column to be a string.

However, after upload, when I query the table, many of the EANs in the table seem to have been rounded.

For example EAN 666151031098 has become EAN 666151000000.

How can I prevent this happening during the upload?

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely an issue that happens when you're exporting the file to csv on your computer. Can you confirm that when you read your csv before importing with a plain text reader the numbers are still unchanged?

Comment: Yes I can confirm I double checked. Even if I try a slightly different method of pasting the csv data into a Google Sheet and creating table from live google sheet (where the numbers are correct), the final table in GBQ still has rounded numbers. An example:

5060420335583 - Google Sheet data
5060420000000  - Google Big Query equivalent

Again, the EAN is defined as a string. I don't think the string definition is an issue as I have defined it as such in other tables with no such issues.